# Jenkins with publish over ssh - unable to migrate server configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using Jenkins (2.32.2) Docker container with the Publish over ssh plugin (1.17) and I have added a new server manually.
The newly added server is another Docker container (both running with docker-compose) and I am using a password to connect to it, and everything works just fine when doing it manually, but the problem is when I'm rebuilding the image.

I am already using a volume for the jenkins gone directory and it works just fine. The problem is only on the initial installation (e.g. image build, not a container restart).

It seems like the problem is with the secret key, and I found out that I also need to copy some keys when creating my image.

[See the credentials section at Publish over ssh documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over)

I tried to copy all the "secrets" directory and the following files: secret.key, secret.key.not-so-secret, identity.key.enc - but I still can't connect after a fresh install.

What am I missing?

Edited:
I just tried to copy the whole jenkins_home directory on my DOCKERFILE and it works, so I guess that the problem is with the first load or something? maybe Jenkins changes the key / salt on the first load?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to push out jenkins config to docker host of to os where docker host is being installed

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

or

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ./local/conf:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not answering my question. I'm already using a volume for the whole jenkins home directory, but the server (publish over ssh) configuration are not working after a fresh install (it works if I save the configuration and restart the container, e.g. when loaded from the volume)